# Given $y=e^{rx}$, for which values of $r$ does $y'' - 2y' - 3y = 0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to solve this problem but I am not able to do it.

$y=e^{rx}$ : For what values of $r$ does $y'' - 2y' - 3y = 0$.
I tried to differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$, but I get something like : $e^{rx}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(rx)$, which does not seem to help me a lot.

How I am supposed to do this ?

Comment: Setting $$y=e^{rx}$$ then $$y'=re^{rx}$$ etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $y=e^{rx}$, $y'=re^{rx}$, $y''=r^2e^{rx}$. Now, we just want to solve 
$$ y''-2y'-3y=0.$$
I.e.,
$$ r^2e^{rx}-2re^{rx}-3e^{rx}=0.$$
We know that $e^{rx}\ne 0$ for $r\in \mathbf{R}$, so we divide through by $e^{rx}$ and find 
$$ r^2-2r-3=(r-3)(r+1)=0.$$
Thus, $r=3,-1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$y=e^{rx} $$
$$y'=ry $$
$$y''=r^2y $$

so you need
$$r^2-2r-3=0$$
or

$$r\in \{-1,3\} $$

Answer (score 1):

$y'$ is short for $\frac {dy}{dx}$ so you should be taking $y'=\frac d{dx}(e^{rx})$ using the chain rule.  This gives $y'=re^{rx}$.  Now do it again to get $y''$ and plug into the equation.  The $e^{rx}$ will divide out, leaving you with a quadratic in $r$